# SQLite query to strip off some text

Tags: string, sqlite

I want to find all records that look like

`Transfer to CHK 9071 Confirmation# 1904952784`

(regardless of the number) and strip off the "Confirmation#" part; so above would become

`Transfer to CHK 9071`

I tried this but got syntax error:

`update ZUSERPAYEE set ZNAME = left (ZNAME,length(ZNAME) - 24) where ZNAME like "%Confirmation#  __________";`

Comment: It works for me. (MySQL 5.6.16) Result: "Transfer to CHK 9071 " with blank at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a little more reliable because it doesn't require the confirmation number to be a fixed length.  And also single quotes for the LIKE.

```
update ZUSERPAYEE 
set ZNAME = INSTR(ZNAME, 'Confirmation#') - 1) 
where ZNAME like '%Confirmation# %'
```

Comment: I tried that, but got `Error: near "(": syntax error` ... maybe it's because I'm using `sqlite3` from the command line on OSX ... maybe it doesn't support the full feature set of MySQL...

Comment: I updated the statement.  I left off the second argument to charindex.

Comment: Changed CHARINDEX to LOCATE.  Same format, but CHARINDEX is for SQL Server.

Comment: Didn't your database tag say mysql earlier?  I will update one more time from locate to position for SQLlite.  I am not a big sqllite guy.

Comment: Yes, my bad! I should've used SQLite, sorry.

Comment: `POSITION` gives syntax error, too. I have a feeling this version of SQLite just won't allow nesting string functions.

Comment: Did you try it with left changed to substr?

Comment: Now it's saying `Error: no such table: ZNAME` ... I think we're looking for `INSTR` (see http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) // NOPE, no such function INSTR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62644/discussion-between-zeev-and-chris-barlow).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you checkout the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function. (I know that's available in MySQL, not sure about SqlLite3)

e.g.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('Transfer to CHK 9071 Confirmation# 1904952784',' Confirmation#',1)
```

(The example assumes that there's always space before Confirmation#, and you want that space removed as well.)

If you just want to trim off starting at 'Confirmation#', omit the space character:

```
 SUBSTRING_INDEX('Transfer to CHK 9071 Confirmation# 1904952784','Confirmation#',1)
```

For the example given, that will leave a trailing space. Trailing spaces could be removed by wrapping that expression in a

```
TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM expr)
```

Comment: Nice, but `Error: no such function: SUBSTRING_INDEX` :-(

Answer (score 0):

try using single quotes instead of double